# OpenERP get next Sequence number

Tags: python, xml, sequence, odoo

OpenERP gives a sequence number when we saved a record. i have done that module.as per that module when i create a worker then load employee number as EMP001,EMP002..

My requirment is this. When I'm going to create a new employee then need to show next sequence number as a read only field.
for ex : when i'm going to create a 9th employee then need to show EMP009 in my emp no field.

my current codes uploaded to below location
https://github.com/priyankahdp/openerp/tree/openerp

NOW ITS SORTED
I ADDED BELOW THERE

```
_defaults = {
     'register_no': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'bpl.worker'),
     }
```

Comment: You mean you want to make your field readonly. Am I right? If so then write `readonly=True` inside field declaration code in your py file.

Comment: @Arya
thanks for the comment.
yeah readonly.but how to load that next number on form load ?

Comment: You can fill it when create method is called.

Comment: when time need to trigger it.in default state.?

Comment: Please not that one should rather use obj.pool.get('ir.sequence').next_by_code(cr, uid, 'bpl.worker', context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your field as `readonly`

```
'register_no': fields.char('Register No', size=32, help='Register No', readonly=True),
```

and mention that in `_default`

Please check in existing module like `sale.py` how they are getting default sequence for the next sales order number.

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/trunk/view/head:/sale/sale.py

Comment: Hi Anne. As Arya mention you can do same in `create` method. But If you want to display before creating that order then you can return that in `_default` please check `_get_default_shop` how it will be use in `_default`. I can write code but if you try then you will get idea how to use it next time. You can also check `def create` for the @Arya's option.